# comparing two integrals: a cancellation method

Tags: integration

Problem: whether proving $\int x\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x < \int x\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is equivalent to proving $\int \, f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x < \int g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$?
I have tried this and want to make sure this is right

Comment: If it is a definite integral... are you assuming the range of x is non negative here i.e. the limits of the integral are non negative?

Comment: the range of x is from -inf to inf

Comment: It isn't equivalent (in general).

Comment: do you know under what conditions it is equivalent?

Answer (score -1):

Since the range is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the answer is no. Here is a counter example. Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^4}$ and $g(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^4}$. Then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^4}dx = 0 < \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xg(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
And yet
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx = \frac{\pi}{2} > \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^4}dx = 0
$$
NOTE: I will not go through the steps to get these integrals. They are ugly. The general idea is just to have $f(x)$ be an even function and $g(x)$ be an odd one. Then, $xf(x)$ is odd and $xg(x)$ is even. The integral of an odd function (given this range) is 0.

Comment: that's beautiful. thanks!

Comment: downvoter, what's wrong?